# Moving partial data across hadoop instances

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have to copy a certain chunk of data from one hadoop cluster to another. I wrote a hive query which dumps the data into hdfs. After copying the file to the destination cluster, I tried to load the data using the command "load data inpath '/a.txt' into table data".  I got the following error message

> Failed with exception Wrong file format. Please check the file's format.
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask

I had dumped the data as a sequence file.  Can anybody let me know what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE` while creating the table if you want to store sequence file in the table. And you have written that you have dumped data as `Sequence file` but your file name is `a.txt`. I didn't get that.

If you want to load a text file into a table that expects Sequence file as the data source you could do one thing. First create a normal table and load the text file into this table. Then do :

```
insert into table seq_table select * from text_table;
```